# Is it possible to view all members of a class using PowerShell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell

As the title of this topic suggests, I'm looking for advice about how to view all members of a class using PowerShell, regardless of whether those members are hidden or not. Is there a way of doing this just by using PowerShell cmdlets?

To give an example, let's say I was looking for members of the System.AppDomain class. If I try to view the class members using Get-Member, the CurrentDomain property is missing:

```
([AppDomain] | Get-Member -View All -Force) | ? {$_.Name -eq 'CurrentDomain'}
```

However, I can find this property if I fall back on using .NET classes directly, for example:

```
(([AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ? {$_.Location -Match 'mscorlib'}).gettypes() | ? {$_.Name -like 'AppDomain'}).GetMembers() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'CurrentDomain' }
```

Using this example as a frame for my earlier question, is it possible to return information about the CurrentDomain property of the AppDomain class just by using the cmdlets available by default in any version of PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets info about CurrentDomain:

```
[system.appdomain] | Get-Member -static | where-object {$_.name -eq "CurrentDomain"}
```

You can read this to get more information on how the `Get-Member` cmdlet works. Essentially, the static switch gives static methods and properties of an object of a particular class. Leaving off the static switch, only provides info about the instance of an object of that class. See [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6)

In your case, you are looking up information about a particular class without an instance because you have not created an object. When you run `Get-Member` cmdlet, you can look at the Definition property and see that they are static methods indicated by the use of the word static

Comment: This is right but would be better with more explanation, like why you need a different parameter (`-Static`), the difference between instance and static members, how to tell you're accessing a static member (`::`).

Comment: Thank you AdminOfThings, happy to accept your answer. briantist, I learnt some things from your answer too (that :: is for accessing static members), thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

You can also use the [`GetMembers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmembers?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetMembers) method of the class `System.RuntimeType`:

```
[System.AppDomain].GetMembers() | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'CurrentDomain'}
```

If you want all members:

```
[System.AppDomain].GetMembers()
```

This can be quite lengthy, so you can format the output to see just the member types (method, property, etc.), names, and definitions:

```
[System.AppDomain].GetMembers() | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap MemberType, Name, @{'n'='Definition';'e'={$_.ToString()}}
```

---

### More details

`GetMembers` returns an array of [`MemberInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo?view=netcore-3.1) objects. For each of these, we're keeping the `MemberType` and `Name` fields, and we're calling the `ToString()` method to see the definition of the member (for example, for a method, it would be the return type along with parameter types).

Based on the value of MemberType, you can even cast `MemberInfo` into [`MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netcore-3.1), [`PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=netcore-3.1), [`FieldInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo?view=netcore-3.1), or [`EventInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.eventinfo?view=netcore-3.1), to name a few.

### Note on `Get-Member`

Using -Static suggests that you already have enough information on the class to know that it is static, or it isn't but you only want static members.

Note that if your class is not static but you use the `-Static` option, you won't see the members that instances of the class would have. For example:

```
$obj = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream "D:\\test.txt", ([System.IO.FileMode]::CreateNew)
$obj | Get-Member
```

Output:

```
   TypeName: System.IO.FileStream

Name                      MemberType Definition
----                      ---------- ----------
BeginRead                 Method     System.IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] array, int offset, int numBytes, System.As...
BeginWrite                Method     System.IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] array, int offset, int numBytes, System.A...
Close                     Method     System.Void Close()
...
ReadTimeout               Property   System.Int32 ReadTimeout {get;set;}
SafeFileHandle            Property   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle SafeFileHandle {get;}
WriteTimeout              Property   System.Int32 WriteTimeout {get;set;}
```

But with `-Static`:

```
$obj | Get-Member -Static
```

Output:

```
   TypeName: System.IO.FileStream

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Equals          Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
ReferenceEquals Method     static bool ReferenceEquals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
Synchronized    Method     static System.IO.Stream Synchronized(System.IO.Stream stream)
Null            Property   static System.IO.Stream Null {get;}
```

`GetMembers` works regardless of the class, and shows you both the class's own (static) members as well as those of its instances.