# Why does `[SomeType] | Get-Member -Static` return static members of `SomeType` instead of those of `System.RuntimeType`?

Tags: powershell, class, types, static

Let's take an example. If understand correctly, `System.IO.FileStream` is a class, but `[System.IO.FileStream]` is an object: it's an instance of the class `System.RuntimeType`.

If I run `[System.IO.FileStream] | Get-Member`, I'll get the members of `System.RuntimeType` (technically, of its instance):

```
   TypeName: System.RuntimeType

Name                           MemberType Definition
----                           ---------- ----------
AsType                         Method     type AsType()
Clone                          Method     System.Object Clone()
Equals                         Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(type o)
FindInterfaces                 Method     type[] FindInterfaces(System.Reflection.TypeFilter filter, System.Object filterCriteria)
...
TypeHandle                     Property   System.RuntimeTypeHandle TypeHandle {get;}
TypeInitializer                Property   System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo TypeInitializer {get;}
UnderlyingSystemType           Property   System.Type UnderlyingSystemType {get;}
```

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member):

> To get information about static members, the members of the class, not of the instance, use the *Static* parameter.

But if I run `[System.IO.FileStream] | Get-Member -Static` now I get:

```
   TypeName: System.IO.FileStream

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Equals          Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
ReferenceEquals Method     static bool ReferenceEquals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
Synchronized    Method     static System.IO.Stream Synchronized(System.IO.Stream stream)
Null            Property   static System.IO.Stream Null {get;}
```

**Q1. These are the static members of `System.IO.FileStream`, not `System.RuntimeType`. Why is that?**

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-static-classes-and-methods) also says:

> We use **::** to indicate to Windows PowerShell that we want to work with a static method or property.

This made me realize that `[System.IO.FileStream]::Null` refers to the static property `Null` of the class `System.IO.FileStream`.

**Q2. Does it mean that Powershell sometimes sees `[System.IO.FileStream]` as the class `System.IO.FileStream` (when dealing with static members), and sometimes as an instance of `System.RuntimeType`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, **[`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) *without* `-Static` *always* acts on the *type* of its input objects**.

`[System.IO.FileStream]` is an *instance* of a PowerShell *type literal* (`[<type-name>]`), whose *type* is `System.RuntimeType`, which is a PowerShell-internal class that derives from [`System.Reflection.TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.TypeInfo) and ultimately [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type).

Therefore, `[System.IO.FileStream] | Get-Member` outputs information about the members of `System.RuntimeType` - and so would *any* type literal (e.g., `[int] | Get-Member` would yield the same output).

---

By contrast, **`Get-Member` *with* `-Static`**:

- **acts on the input object itself *if* it happens to be a `System.RunTimeType` instance**, such as type literal `[System.IO.FileStream]`; otherwise, as usual, the input object's *type* is operated on.
- reports only the *static* members of the input object / type.

Therefore, `[System.IO.FileStream] | Get-Member -Static` reports the static members of type [`System.IO.FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileStream) - as would passing an *instance* of type `System.IO.FileStream`; e.g., `[System.IO.FileStream]::new($PROFILE, 'Open') | Get-Member -Static`

---

A curious omission, **as of PowerShell Core 7.0**, is that **you cannot use `Get-Member` to request *instance* members *by type***; the only way to get a type's instance members is to pass an actual *instance* as input; however, the challenge is that an instance is not always easy to come by, so getting instance members by type would be helpful, 
which [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6382) requests.

In the meantime, you can call `.GetMembers()` on a type, as you demonstrate in your own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584953/6096232).

Comment: @Narvarth: The docs have been amended (not quite in the way I had hoped, but the "NOTES" section will mention the behavior), and the changes will be published soon.